# Update and Install problems with Eclipse

Tags: linux, eclipse, ide

When I try to install/update any plugin from Help -> Install New Software I receive error messages like this:

```
No repository found at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/galileo.
```

or

```
Unable to connect to repository http://pydev.org/updates/site.xml
Invalid argument
```

This happens with all Eclipse versions.

I use Eclipse on Debian Sid.

Comment: I've had no problem just now with the galileo update site you just mentioned. So it is either on your side or just a temporary failure from eclipse.org

Comment: Thanks for feedback. It's like I supposed: this problem is my pc.

Comment: Connecting in the browser to site.xml works though? Are you in any special network?

Comment: In the browser works fine. No, I'm not in a special network.

Comment: I got a timeout trying to access http://download.eclipse.org/releases/galileo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, try running eclipse with these options: 
 -vmargs -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

It worked for me

(see https://lists.launchpad.net/openjdk/msg03123.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling proxies inside Eclipse. This helped me once.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some generic eclipse error resolution steps I use:

1) Try run eclipse with the -clean option. This should cleanup some stuff. No clue if it helps with your problem, but maybe worth a try?

2) Delete .metadata directory (or move it temporarily away) from your workspace and run eclipse with the -clean option again.

3) (Skip if you have tried this) Try download another eclipse installation into another local directory and try to see if that works out of the box.  If it works, your former eclipse installation was bugged. If it does not work, I suggest checking your general network access to the specific urls you mention.